# Is there a way to save all state of a .NET AppDomain and restore on demand?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, state

I need a lightweight approach to saving current state of my application before making changes to object instances. The solution needs to be able to restore the state before changes were made (Undo/redo) for the entire process.

Comment: What you've done so far? Serializing/deserializing `viewModel` and storing it to `xml` or any other storage?

Comment: Yes, viewModel save using INPC events. But, I dont want to have to consider side effects of changes. On UNDO, side effects would remain. So, going back to a snapshot of process would be better.